# html nested tables not showing properly

Tags: html

I am trying to do nested tables but they are not shown properly (although I specified the width of each table division and they are the same in all the tables). Can you please spot where the problem is, or suggest a way to avoid problems such as these?

http://arbsq.net/canvas/tmp/out_aligned_table.htm

Comment: Please try to be a bit more helpful when it comes to specifying where you are having trouble.  You have over 4000 table rows and I have no clue which part is troubling you.

Comment: it's basically that the td's are not vertically aligned, this appears from the first table

Comment: for example the td which has "Español" should be exactly on top of the one "Original: inglés", but you can see it is shifted

Comment: Why are you using multiple tables? Keep in mind, a `<table>` element can have many `<tbody>` children.

Comment: Also keep in mind, there can only be one *unique* `id` per document. I see about 178 elements with `id="r0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they vary in width is because some of the tables are being pushed to a full 100% width by the content within the table where as some are not.

If you want all of your tables to look like the ones that are the full width of the window then you need to set the `width` of `table` to 100%

Also, it would make more sense to use one table instead of many.  That way, everything will be the same width and align.

Answer (score 4):

Couple things.

First thing's first: validate your HTML.

- you may not have a `table` directly inside a `table`. You may, however, contain a `table` within a `td`. If you want to nest tables (not saying you *should*, but if you want to), you can put them inside table cells.
- one unique ID per document. You may not have `id="r0"` 178 times in the same document. I fixed the row IDs but you will have to fix the checkbox IDs.
- the `title` element must be in the `head` not the `body`. I've moved it to its correct place.
- last thing, but optional: all `td`s in Spanish should have the `lang="es"` attribute for Search Engine Optimization. You'll have to do this yourself.

Now for some major overhauls.

- semantically, all this data really belongs in one single `table`. I removed all tables and used `tbody`s instead. Yes, the `table` element may contain multiple `tbody` children. A few search-and-replaces took care of this.  **Incidentally, this will fix your table width problem**. I also moved the section IDs from the `table`s to the `tbody`s.
- line indenting, for readability. You posted your work on this site, expecting some review and feedback no? Do your reviewers a favor and make them want to read your code. At first when I saw the source I was like, "aw, hell naw." But then I decided to tackle it with a simple search-and-replace (using `\n` to insert newlines and `\t` to insert tabs). Most readers would have not given your code a second glance.
- CSS styles. There is absolutely zero reason you need to have `border="1"` on each of the 178 tables. Or worse, have the width specified on every single cell. That's 6,000 cells, at a bare minimum! Not only is the `width` attribute deprecated in HTML5, it is not very DRY (don't repeat yourself). What would happen if you wanted to change the widths? How many lines would you have to change? There are more than 35,000. I fixed it by adding 8 lines of CSS.

[Here's the file with all the changes.](https://gist.github.com/chharvey/9913604)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code show table ID `align` is wrapping table ID `section0`:

```
<table border="1" id="align"><table border="1" id="section0">
```

Although inspecting the element in google chrome developer tools showing that this is not the case and table `align` is empty.

You must have some unclosed HTML tags - but whith 10000000 rows it's impossible to locate the problems and where you forgot to close the HTML tag.

Comment: It appears the OP is intentionally wrapping `table`s within the `table#align`. This is not valid HTML: the `table` element may not have a `table` element as a direct child. A `td` element, however, may.